# Using IF commands to Check if a button exists in Selenium Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have a java selenium program that automatically presses on a button in a website. The code i am using looks like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
```

I want the program to use if statements if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need for an `if` statement there. If `findElement` can't find the button, then it will throw an exception. You might want a try/catch block, possibly. You can learn about if and try/catch on the internet. [This site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: i am using the try/catch but can i driver.quit insted of printing out the error?

Comment: You can. Or just finish your execution flow in the normal way. If your mini-application is just pushing a button, then it's safe to just let it finish and everything will tidy up nicely. Java finalization will clean everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public void ClickButton () throws InterruptedException
{
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));
String Source = driver.getPageSource();
if (Source.contains(button))
    {
    button.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
else
    {
    driver.quit;
    }
}
```

Hope this can be helpful. Let me know if you are still facing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use findelements by along with if to achieve this. Below code might give you some idea.

```
if(driver.findElements(by.xpath("//*[@id=253]")).size>0)
{
//element exists with id = 253 
// do the stuff
} else
{
//element do not exist with id = 253. 
// do the stuff
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.